# Как определить минимальные системные требования для собственной программы?

Tags: java

Пишу диплом, собственно есть необходимость в записи информации о сделанной программе в записке диплома (desktop приложение). Язык - java. Да и так вопрос сам по себе интересный.

Comment: Интересный вопрос...

Comment: Интересно, правда...

Для этого, скорее всего используются какой-нибудь специализированный софт, к которому тяжело получить доступ рядовому пользователю...

Comment: Прикинуть максимум памяти, которое необходимо программе, не думаю, что очень сложно. С процессором, сложнее, но не на много, разве что у вас не критические вычисления, которые требуют много процессорного времени. Если делать "на глаз", то посмотрите в диспетчере задач, сколько "под нагрузкой" выделяется вашему приложению. В крайнем случае, думаю, что подойдет параметр из JVM.

Comment: Ну написать отсебятину в дипломе мало что мешает. Теперь уже стало интересно как компании-разработчки софта это делают)

Comment: Хм...странно, но мне почему-то кажется, что большинство разработчиков ПО пишут требования наугад. Например, существуют сотни игр с ценой<50 рублей. В таком случае вряд ли разработчики станут прогонять игру по разным анализаторам( не бесплатным ), они лучше напишут требования, какие им самим кажутся более-менее правдоподобными. Иначе, их софтина будет нести скорее убытки, чем прибыль.

Comment: > какой-нибудь специализированный софт, к которому тяжело получить доступ

вишмастер что-ли?

Comment: Для определения минимума можно поставить виртуальную машину и гонять программу на ней, делать тесты с разным объёмом памяти и выделенного процессорного времени. Экспериментально определить границу за которой уже сыплются ошибки.

Answer (score 5):

Есть такая интересная штука, называется профайлер. Так вот я думаю запустить там твою программку и посмотреть что ей надо.. а потом на глаз прикинуть минимальную железяку для нее

а минимальные требования - необходима JVM

Answer (score 2):

Минимальные это те, при которых программа будет работать. Не абсолютно минимальные, ниже которых компьютер скажет "нет, я не буду это выполнять", а просто минимальные.

Самый простой вариант. Берем свою девелоперскую машину, и отталкиваемся от нее. Минимальные - на поколение-пару старше, рекомендуемые - чуть помощнее. Это конечно, если девелоперская машина не хайэнд класса, на которой все летает...

Есть еще вариант. Идем в какой-нить инетмагаз компутеров и смотрим какие нынче компы называются офисными, ставим минимальную планку чуть ниже этой конфигурации...

А вообще конечно, производительность, потребление памяти, диск и т.д. можно точно вычислить, но в большинстве случаев это касается железожадных софтин, системные требования, для которых, могут отличаться взависимости от клиента. Яркий пример 1с - от старенького компа бухгалтера, до стойки с серваками на несколько сот килобаксов. Тут понятие минимальные требования размыто... Для "простых" десктопных утилит это не так важно. Захотят запустить программу,  вряд ли станут комп под нее покупать...